# Different display of ticks in windows and linux

Tags: plotting, fonts, windows, ticks, linux

I made my code on a windows computer, mathematica 11.0.1. For the plots I used self defined ticks. Here all the ticks are shown. However, I did simulations on a linux computer (also mathemativa v11.0.1), and will have to generate the plots there. On linux the ticks are different. There is a little more spacing, the font is slightly bigger and now the first tick disappears (see images). I have been through all kind of settings, and can not find what causes this. Any suggestions?

Example code to generate plots:

```
labels = {"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(2\), \(n/3\)]\)", 
  "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(2\), \(\(\\\ \)\(2n/3\)\)]\)", 
  "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(2\), \(\(\\\ \)\(n\)\)]\)", 
  "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(2\), \(\(\\\ \)\(7n/6\)\)]\)", 
  "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(2\), \(\(\\\ \)\(4n/3\)\)]\)", 
  "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(2\), \(5\\\n/3\)]\)", 
  "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(2\), \(2n\)]\)"}

Qlist = {6, 26, 128, 288, 646, 3251, 16384}

labels2 = Table[{Qlist[[i]], labels[[i]]}, {i, 1, 7}]
pltstylv = "DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Monochrome", ListLinePlot]);
pmrkrs = PlotMarkers /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["OpenMarkersThick", ListLinePlot];
fakeData = Table[{Qlist[[i]], i^2}, {i, 1, 7}];

ListPlot[{fakeData}, PlotRange -> {Full, Full}, ImageSize -> 700, 
 Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> pltstylv, 
 PlotMarkers -> pmrkrs, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
 Ticks -> {labels2, Automatic}]
```

Different results:
linux
[image: Linux]
windows
[image: windows]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a *minimum* working example.

Comment: I could get rid of the legend to make it smaller, but the plotstyle, the logscale the image size etc. all influence the outcome, so it is quite minimal allready. How do I edit my post?

Comment: I edited the code example to make it smaller

Comment: Font rendering is different on each operating system. Try exporting to PDF instead of taking a screenshot.  Do this using `Export` and *not* using right click, save graphics as... Is there still a difference?

Comment: Also if you are not satisfied with the quality of math typesetting, give MaTeX a try.

Comment: @Szabolcs Exporting has exactly the same problem (looks identical). The font in linux seems to be bigger in general (also in de titles and legends of plots), and there is more whitespace in the linux version, the same as in the pictures here. The quality does not matter so much for me, but it should display ALL the ticks in some not to shabby manner.

Comment: It is the larger font used for the tick labels that is causing the problem. When a label gets too big near axes crossing it is suppressed.

Comment: Are you sure that you tried *exactly* what I asked and that you compared the PDFs with the same viewer on the same system? I get non-identical but very similar PDF outputs on Mac and Linux. The Linux one doesn't have the problems you showed. https://www.dropbox.com/s/fg0qrmhsqq5vlmt/Screenshot%202017-01-31%2009.05.50.png?dl=0

Comment: Yes. Weirdly, you do not have the whitespace between the numbers in the exponent. Any clue why I have that and you do not? There is also more whitespace in the linux version in labels and titles of the plots.